# Python3 matplotlib.pyplot plots 10,11,12.. before 2 20,21,22... before 3 etc

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting from a text file but my x axis is putting 10 before 2, 20 before 3 etc. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkILC.png).

When I run my program multiple times, these plots are also inconsistent, even with the same input text file.

When I run it on my another computer, the plots are fine. But on my ubuntu machine, this happens every time.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

x = [];
y = [];

opened = 0;

try:
    readFile = open('xy.txt','r');
    opened = 1;
except:
    print('some error occurred!');

if opened:

    for line in readFile:
        splitUp = line.split();
        x.append(splitUp[0]);
        y.append(splitUp[1]);

        print(splitUp[0] + ',' + splitUp[1]);

    plt.plot(x,y);
    readFile.close();

    plt.show();
```

Comment: what was the output of `print(splitUp[0] + ',' + splitUp[1]);` ?

Comment: This is of course not reproducible. Please post a [mcve] of the issue. Best use some text buffer (`io.StringIO`) or at least provide the input data in an accesible way.

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays `x` and `y` are arrays of strings, so they are sorted alphabetically, so the order is like : 1, 10, 11, 2, 20, 25. You can try with  `x.append(int(splitUp[0]))`